# Trouble with image hover/onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have an image on my site that is set to cursor: pointer; and a function to show a hidden element when clicked. For some reason it is not working at all. Nothing happens when I hover over it or when I click it. Below is a screenshot and the code. Thanks!!

[image]

HTML:

```
  <div class="font-wrap">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p class="talk-bubble">
       Join the Conversation
      </p>
        <p class="sign-in">
          Sign In to Comment
        </p>
        <img class="sign-in-img" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/sign-in.png" />
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.pagecontent .cols .col.two .font-wrap {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .wrapper {
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:0px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  z-index:-2;
}   
.pagecontent .cols .col.two .wrapper .sign-in-img {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .wrapper .sign-in-img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .sign-in {
  text-align:right;
  margin:0;
  margin-right:50px;
  padding:0;
  font-size: .6em;
  color: #808C8D;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .talk-bubble {
  border:1px solid #3A7DBA;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color:#CDE5F7;
  position:relative;
  margin-right:60px;
  color: #3A7DBA;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .talk-bubble:before, .talk-bubble:after {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0;
  content:'';
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  border:20px solid transparent;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .talk-bubble:before {
  z-index:-1;
  border-bottom:20px solid #3A7DBA;
  right:-12px;
  bottom:-1px;
}

.pagecontent .cols .col.two .talk-bubble:after {     
  border-bottom:20px solid #CDE5F7;
  right:-10px;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

JS:

```
  $( ".sign-in-img" ).click(function() {
    $('.comments-container').show('slow');
  });
```

Comment: Where is your div class comments-container?

Answer (score 1):

It has something to do with your Selector :

```
.pagecontent .cols .col.two .wrapper .sign-in-img
```

this does not point you to the wanted image.
Using this would work:

```
.sign-in-img{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Btw, if you're using it often i would suggest you to put this css code:

```
.cursPoint{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and then add the class curspoint in all tags you're using it! eg.

```
<img class="sign-in-img cursPoint" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/sign-in.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still not working though :/ This is really stumping me.

Comment: @MrDevRI do you have any other code there, I tried it and it's working fine. maybe you should try and delete the z-index too (or at least change it) :)

Comment: It was the z-index -2. thanks man i must have overlooked that.